# How to create SQLite in-memory database at specific address

Tags: sqlite, mmap, in-memory-database, ramdisk

I want to use SQLite to store some metadata information within a file. This file is already mmap'd. What I want to be able to do is create a SQLite DB, passing in a char* to tell it where to make the DB, instead of having it allocate its own. Can this be done? SQLite docs for in-memory databases just say to use ":memory:", and that the DB will be destroyed at end of process, with no indication of how to use already-existing data or persist it.

If not, what workarounds are there on Linux? Is there an "inverse" mmap, so I can take an address and map it to a new file? (So /foo would be a view onto a part of /bar?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-memory databases are just databases whose page cache is not saved to disk.

There is no mechanism to access these pages.

Your only choice would be to implement your own [VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html) to redirect file accesses to the correct part of that file.

Comment: "In-memory databases are just databases whose page cache is not saved to disk."  That must be in reference specifically to SQLite in-memory databases, because it is definitely not true of in-memory database systems in general.

Answer (score 5):

A VFS is definitely the way to go, but you don't even need to write your own: The sqlite3 distribution contains a file `ext/misc/memvfs.c` that already implements what you need:

```
USAGE:

sqlite3_open_v2("file:/whatever?ptr=0xf05538&sz=14336&max=65536", &db,
                   SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_URI,
                   "memvfs");

These are the query parameters:

   ptr=          The address of the memory buffer that holds the database.

   sz=           The current size the database file

   maxsz=        The maximum size of the database.  In other words, the
                 amount of space allocated for the ptr= buffer.

   freeonclose=  If true, then sqlite3_free() is called on the ptr=
                 value when the connection closes.

The ptr= and sz= query parameters are required.  If maxsz= is omitted,
then it defaults to the sz= value.  Parameter values can be in either
decimal or hexadecimal.  The filename in the URI is ignored.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a SQLite expert, but it seems like you could use the information here to use your own allocator, and control the memory location at which SQLite creates the in-memory database:  https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mem_methods.html

Comment: But you don't know what allocation is used for what purpose.

Comment: Does it matter?  If your objective is control what memory SQLite uses (i.e. know/control the memory address at which the IMDB is created), it seems like this does it.  Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: I don't even mind creating it on-disk. But I need to open it from memory. Looks like a VFS is the way to go.